# find the memory usage of lru_cache decorator

Tags: python, caching, python-lru-cache

I want to track the memory usage of *lru_cached* class method.
I know how to extract the number of method calls

```
from functools import lru_cache

class Exponent:
    def __init__ (self, base):
         self.base = base
         
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)     
    def __call__(self, exponent):
        return self.base ** exponent
    
exponent_base_two = Exponent(2)
exponent_base_two(2);
exponent_base_two(3);
exponent_base_two.__call__.cache_info()
```

output:

```
CacheInfo(hits=2, misses=2, maxsize=None, currsize=2)
```

However, I'm looking for a method to extract *cache* size in bytes (similar to `sys.getsizeof` output)